# What module do I need, to make a light stay on for 2 minutes and then turn off?

Tags: dc, 12v, delay

I have a quick question. I am trying to create a box where the button is clicked; the light comes on for 2 minutes. I am using a 12-volt battery to power this. I want to know what module I need for the bulb to stay on for 2 mins and then turn off. Could someone help?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I suggest that you submit the same question in other sites, too. This site most of times is for especific technical questions that you find when trying to build a device like this. If you just want that someone points to you which module you should buy, I'm afraid that this kind of help is beyond this site's objectives.

Comment: @mguima I want to know what module I need is this not technical. What other sites should I go to? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You should be able to find an "off-delay timer 12V" on a web search.

Comment: An MCU? A PLC? A timer?

Comment: RahulVijayan: This site could only help if you want to build a device like that you described. For building, a simple approach would use a 555 IC in monostable configuration (Google for _"555 monostable"_); a somewhat more precise, but more complicated approach would need an microcontroller. Google for _"Arduino and relay module"_. But, there would be necessary to write a computer-like program for using it in Arduino. But if you just want to buy ready commercial product, this [one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000829300329.html) seems to address your necessity, and it's very configurable.

Comment: you can just but a "timer relay" module for a few bucks, no need to mess around with ICs.

Comment: You may search for 'automotive timer relay'.

Answer (score 1):

The device you're looking for is usually called a "monostable multivibrator", that is it can be in multiple states and one of them is stable. The most common implementation is the 555 IC, although it lacks precision in timing. If precise timing is needed a microcontroller is probably easier.

You will likely also need a voltage controlled switch of some kind, unless your light is very low power. This could be a MOSFET (for low-medium power DC devices), a relay (for AC devices or higher power DC devices) or a Solid State Relay (SSR) (for AC devices where fast switching, high reliability, or quiet operation is required).

Comment: I hope that I'll live to see the end of 555. Probably I will die before.